# How to correctly delete an entity and get feedback (Play/Ebean)?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

In my Play2 application, I have a model class called *user*. It contains a delete-method:

```
public static void delete(Long id) {
    find.ref(id).delete();
}
```

The delete-action in my controller looks like this:

```
public static Result deleteUser(Long id) {
    User user = User.find.ref(id);
    if(user == null) {
        return notFound();
    } else {
        User.delete(id);
        return ok();
    }
}
```

My intention is to give feedback if the user exists before trying to delete it. Otherwise I always get the following exception if a user does not exist:

> [OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows
>   sql[delete from user where id=?]

But the `find.ref` method I used in my controller never returns `null`, regardless if a user exists or not. Because of this, the delete-method always gets called and the exception I mentioned above raises.

How to do that correctly? I could use `find.byId` instead of `find.ref` (byId should return null as expected), but I don't want to load the whole data in order to check if a user exists.

**edit:** apart from the question above, why do I get an OptimisticLockException when trying to delete an user that does not exist? Doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Result deleteUser(Long id) {
    User user = User.find.byId(id);
    if(user == null) {
        return notFound();
    } else {
        user.delete();
        return ok();
    }
}
```

Of course instead of loading whole object with relations you can build much simpler query - ie, get `id` field only:

```
User user = User.find.select("id").where().eq("id",id).findUnique();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I already mentioned, find.byId is a possible solution. But if I'm not wrong, it loads the whole user with all its attributes from the database which is a bit too much overhead in my opinion.